# Can a Django View delegate to a function who returns a response object?

Tags: python, django

```
def process_event(request, eventID, eventData):
    return HttpResponse("process event!")

@csrf_exempt 
@slip_protect
def catch_event(request,eventID):       
    if request.POST:               
        process_event(request,eventID, request.POST['eventData'])
        return HttpResponse("safe return!")
```

That code returns "Safe Return!" on client side, and not "process event!". Is that by design and expected behavior? I want to delegate to a function from a view, function should return a response object. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i guess you want `return process_event()`, so that your view returns whatever it gets back

as it currently reads, your view executes `process_event` but throws away the returned `HttpResponse`

Comment: please see the edited code, I have added request as one of the parameters. Shouldn't that aid in returning response thrown by process_event? or its in django by design? View_func can only return usable Response object?

Comment: The request is unimportant. You can only return one response.

Comment: that essentially means view_func once added to stack is final. called functions returning response object is not actually sent to client. I was kinda expecting behavior like nested loop calls. the earliest return found, will be used.

Comment: @trappedIntoCode, I don't understand how else it could possibly work. Django is Python, and in Python if one function calls a second one, returning from the second goes back to the first.

Comment: maybe you can explain what you are actually trying to achieve. There are ways to "return early" for errors, by e.g. raising a Http404 exception

Comment: but django does not have control on python call stack, so it cant handle or does not bother with early response returns.@second I have to call one of a  dozen event handlers depending on event ID. II was hoping to return response from them.

Comment: how do they signify whether or not they can deal with the request? if they return None, you could look for this in your view code, and move to the next one

Comment: I have an event registry, event ID is used to pick appropriate function. So they will handle the request and send appropriate response (a string always) depending on data. The method in your answer will work for me. The problem was, I expected different behavior from HttpResponse and view function calls.

Comment: yes. But I will prolly raise a request on Trac to see what django people think of it. Such behavior if comes from HttpResponse is not totally out of place.

Comment: This is correct Python behavior. You execute process_event, don't store it's result and then return new HttpResponse. The only restriction by Django is that view **must** return a HttpResponse object.